# RabbitMQ AMQP messages and TIBCO 5.10

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, tibco, tibco-business-works

We are using TIBCO 5 and need to consume and publish messages to RabbitMQ AMQP messages.

As far as I have researched and tested there is no support for AMQP messages in TIBCO 5, there is however in TIBCO 6 but upgrade is not an option.

I have tried by putting rabbit mq java client jar in lib directories and using the JMS pallet it connects to Rabbit mq but crash on reading the message.

I wonder if others faced this issue or how they manged to fix this using TIBCO 5.

How about a custom Java starter that does this ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible by a custom java starter, Rabbitmq java code is straight forward. But first i would investigate why the jms driver crashed as this is the most feasible way. Did you investigate the error ? Most likely class version or dependency errors

Comment: No issue with class etc as it establises the connection but fails when message arrives in the queue complains about some headers, so my guess is that the AMQP message format is not supported or fails to handle etc.

Answer (score -1):

I answer my own question but at the end we actually implemented our own Process starter/Java event source.

The Java event source pallet is pritty simple to use following is how the starter code will look like

```
/**
 *
 * @param processName sampleInputParam
 * @throws Exception exception
 */
public void initProcess(final String processName) throws Exception {
    this.processName = processName;
    init();
}

@Override
public void init() throws Exception {
    LOGGER.info("[ProcessStarter] Initializing " + processName + " Proces Starter");
    //Some init code
    LOGGER.info("[ProcessStarter] Successfully Initialized Proces Starter");
}
```

Following is how its called from tibco

[Java event source pallet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfmIC.png)

The out put from event source is a java object we convert it to a string using the java method activity the code is

```
public String getMessageBodyAsString(final Object message) {
    final MessageDataType messageDataType = (MessageDataType) message;
    return messageDataType.toString();
}
```

If anyone is interested its documented at [Tibco java event source](https://aliawanz.com/2018/01/15/tibco-java-event-source/)